# Проблема удаления изображений после сборки из них видео с помощью Accord.Video.FFMPEG

Tags: c#

```
FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
videoSource.NewFrame += VideoSource_NewFrame;
videoSource.Start();
//сохранение кадров в изображения на диск.
videoSource.SignalToStop();
videoSource.WaitForStop();

using (VideoFileWriter videoWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
{
    videoWriter.Open(outputFileName, width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

    foreach (string image in inputImageSequence)
    {
        Bitmap frame = Image.FromFile(image) as Bitmap;
        videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(frame);
    }
    videoWriter.Close();
}

//удаление сохраненных изображений
```

У меня возникает проблема удаления изображений только если я собираю из них видео. Если убрать код делающий видео, всё спокойно удаляется. Причем часть изображений удаляются, а небольшая последняя их часть нет. Проблема в том, что они занятым каким-то процессом, хотя вроде все занимающие их процессы были закрыты.

Comment: Нужно освобождать ресурсы. Делается это вызовом `frame.Dispose();`. Или использовать `using Bitmap frame ...`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, первый вариант помог!

Comment: @Dreger но лучше использовать второй https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects